# как пользователю ограничить ставить "нравится" один раз?

Tags: java, spring

у меня проект сделать сайт как stack overflow но тока для отзывов для товаров, пишу на java spring boot, в моем проекте можно оставить вопрос и можно отвечать на эти вопросы и могут ставить + или - вопрос как сделать так чтобы один пользователь мог тока один раз плюс поставить?

```
public Question postMarkToQuestion(Long questionId, String mark) {
    Question question = questionRep.findById(questionId).get();
    if(mark.equals("+")){
        question.setLikes(question.getLikes() + 1);
    }
    else if(mark.equals("-")){
        question.setDislikes(question.getDislikes() + 1);
    }
    questionRep.save(question);
    return question;
}
```

Comment: Первая мысль - у каждого пользователя есть уникальный id. У каждого вопроса и ответа есть списки проголосовавших. Если пользователь ставит плюс, то его id добавляется в этот список. Когда пользователь ставит плюс, его id сравнивается со всеми id в списке(бд), и если находится такой же id, то не давать проголосовать пользователю

Comment: super spasibo vam

Answer (score 0):

Перенесу мысль из комментария в ответ. Если вы используете не списки, а базу данных - то списки нужно заменить на таблицы в базе данных.

1. У каждого пользователя есть уникальный `id`(например, с каждой регистрацией прибавляется +1 к числу зарегистрированных пользователей).
2. У каждого вопроса или ответа есть списки хранящие `id` пользователей, которые проголосовали за ответ/вопрос.
3. Когда пользователь хочет проголосовать, его `id` сравнивается со списком уже проголосовавших за этот вопрос/ответ. Если его `id` уже в списке - то нельзя давать проголосовать еще раз.